# Xamarin Sample Apps for iPad and iPhone?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I wonder why none of the Xamarin Prebuilt Apps at https://www.xamarin.com/prebuilt support both iPad **and** iPhone? They all have the same design on each resolution. Especially Apps like 'Acquaint' would be perfect on iPad to have the contact list on the left and the details on the right. But instead it just has the same design like the iPhone Version.....

Are there any reasons why Xamarin does not offer samples with different designs depending on the client resolution? Are there somewhere else some examples?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at our [Creating Mobile Apps with Xamarin.Forms Book First Edition](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/) by Charles Petzold.

I work on the same team as Charles and I know it's a topic he's covered in detail. The full book should be available soon too.

BTW, we are looking into creating some detailed, annotated cross-platform app samples that do all the goodies that a typical modern app would be expected to have.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, i'll have a closer look at the book, especially Chapter 25 about Master-Details-Pags. Is there any way to register somewhere to be alerted by email as soon as your samples are available?

Comment: Sorry, but we don't have anywhere to register for doc/sample update notifications (however that is a great idea, I'll bring that up at the next Docs meeting). I would suggest keeping an eye on the [Xamarin Blog](https://blog.xamarin.com) and our [Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com), as we'll be announcing new additions there.

Comment: I've just downloaded Xamarins official Evolve App at https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve and there it's the same, e.g. on the Event-Tab: Why isn't the list on the left and the details on the right then? Wouldn't it be easier for the users? So they needn't go back to the list and forth to the next event etc. So it's not just a technical question, but I also try to understand WHY they don't do it. I'm sure it's not a technical limitation. And we are talking about a sample app which probably many developers use as a 'guideline'....

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any of the stock Xamarin examples that use `OnIdiom`, but it just a matter of time to code them...hahahah, always just a matter of time and code. (I'm sure the Xamarin guys can chime in on this one):

[Xamarin.Forms.OnIdiom Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.OnIdiom%601/)

```
<OnIdiom.Phone>Vertical</OnIdiom.Phone>
<OnIdiom.Tablet>Horizontal</OnIdiom.Tablet>
```

In terms of finding examples that use the Xamarin.Forms XAML `OnIdiom` I would search Github for `OnIdiom`, there a few OSS examples of phone/tablet switching floating around there as I used at least one as a template to do a quick phone/tablet prototype for a client.